# Fixing numeric cell in a formula in excel on a Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to use repeat a formula with some constants noted in an assumption table how do I do so in Excel on a Mac.  In Excel on a non Apple device the formula would be something like this =B3*(G$4$/A3).

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is a bit off.  For absolute cell reference, the $ sign should precede the Column/Row identifiers. This works on both PC's and Mac.

It should be:

```
 =B3*($G$4/A3)
```

[See here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/training/get-to-know-excel-enter-formulas-RZ006107930.aspx?section=13).